# Separate lru for each argument value?

Tags: python, python-2.x, lru

I need to write a sql database column getter, that takes in a column name and time, and returns the entire column of values for that column corresponding to the input time. This may be a frequent function call with the same arguments, so I would like to use an lru cache. However, I'm not sure if the frequency of the column names is uniformly distributed, so ideally, I would have a separate lru cache for each column name.

I previously had it like below, but I would like to separate the lru for each `col_name`.

```
@lru_cache(...)
def get_col(self, col_name, time)
  # do stuff to get the column and return it
```

How can I achieve this? Also, unfortunately, I have to support py2.

Comment: Is the `@lru_cache` you are using in Python 2 a backport using some external library?

Comment: @matszwecja I'm actually not familiar (I'm working in an existing codebase). I think it's customized and based on the one in `functools`. the one in functools if for py3+ iirc

Comment: So are you writing for Python2 or Python3? Writing something that will work for both is not a viable solution, and Python2 is pretty much a dead language for over 3 years now.

Comment: @matszwecja I have to write in py2 for this particular case. I don't have a say on what version of python I can use

Comment: Okay, at least it's not 2 different versions. I might try to come up with something that should be portable to Py2, but never wrote anything in 2, so any differences you'd have to adapt to on your own.

Comment: @matszwecja okay, thanks. I'd be curious about a py3 answer as well because this might be a common use case in the future for other py3-only codebases

Answer (score 5):

Since [`functools#lru_cache()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) was introduced only with Python 3.x, you will need to manage separate cache dictionaries for each column name, meaning:

- Create an LRU cache class or use a third-party library that supports Python 2 to implement LRU cache functionality.
- Inside your function, maintain a dictionary where each key is a column name and the value is an instance of an LRU cache.
- Before fetching the column data in the `get_col` function, check if the column name is in the dictionary. If it is, use the associated LRU cache to get the data. If it is not, create a new LRU cache for that column name.

Something like this `LRUCache` class:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

class LRUCache(object):
    def __init__(self, maxsize=3): # Adjust maxsize as necessary
        self.cache = OrderedDict()
        self.maxsize = maxsize

    def get(self, key):
        sentinel = object()
        value = self.cache.pop(key, sentinel)
        if value is sentinel:
            return None
        else:
            # If key was in dictionary, reinsert it at the end
            self.cache[key] = value
            return value

    def put(self, key, value):
        if len(self.cache) >= self.maxsize:
            # Remove oldest entry
            self.cache.popitem(last=False)
        self.cache[key] = value

# Dictionary to hold separate LRU caches for each column name
column_caches = {}

def get_col(col_name, time):
    # Get the LRU cache for the specified column name
    # If it does not exist, create a new one
    cache = column_caches.get(col_name)
    if cache is None:
        cache = LRUCache(maxsize=3) # Adjust maxsize as necessary
        column_caches[col_name] = cache

    # Try to get the value from the cache
    result = cache.get(time)
    if result is not None:
        print(cache.cache) # Print the state of the cache
        return result

    # If the value is not in the cache, fetch it
    result = "{} at {}".format(col_name, time) # Dynamic data generation based on input parameters

    # Store the fetched value in the cache and return it
    cache.put(time, result)
    print(cache.cache) # Print the state of the cache
    return result

# Testing
print(get_col('foo', 1))
print(get_col('foo', 2))
print(get_col('foo', 3))
print(get_col('foo', 4))
print(get_col('foo', 3))
print(get_col('foo', 1))
```

Output: ([demo `tio.run`](https://tio.run/##nVTbatwwEH33VwzZh9hgFpr0KbCF0qWlUNqStk8hGMUeJ0ptyUjjJNuQb9@OLMmXJaEXw4KtmTlz5ujMdju60epkv6@NbqHUTYMlSa0syLbThuCLqdBgtZUlJUnZCGvh0/mPd6K8wVRf3XJ2dpYAPxXWUBRSSSqK1GJT59CKByt/4eY0O4MVvK1ue0vxEIQFhSVaK8xuAHCPq1uXDhw289ZptkyJIJsIl4wcrpFC@5@4C9x8nSKpsOEaz3uGeSea3oFN7ded7lIGyMe6KVvWoUDaMTr1cY9B6o2Cz1rheI6NxWXWCj7WjiTcsxZSQSUH6VmPnBGkssj6SwJBQCwIqmpRPpG9YJBLpj@weo6ID4wSdf1MotxHZ0rxfA2qdMLP4M1mofvhHOfY6jsE3VTIN8ySzK50SdXpKgnblJ1Em/eCRcmSP02UrGA7agOk4YY7cXYnjCB0foShykKtDSC/Oif3rQIlWkz8exFSNvD4lCTBKQXHUv4VLjEHkm0UYgUf0Os@wg/o7sR2WMpaYrVoM14pX1mluZPSrMWDtJRDadAxFWz5e4iuiD5f8Fs7/0ZGXhq@D5/KfnOWmtSPCONGThv3lwu36H0R@zrph6MkTPXd634dJPH2H/4y3KdP9X6zfUOxephl0DTOEeLSi7McpjNS8ehDYbDdCr66Qy86OQV1fdBx5nIPnkwXMVENDXnJxuocaiR2iqQl86PHJ7dxj09Ha77vVtChPxh7u@NvWUIlSLAoCtmH7E64EpZNwS9S8Y6B82eLhMZGUt9IGxw4DM05OfCbEQOhqjhSIBdWp/dq5oGsV/X/ZDuQjG@YN1eq68TDxdU4rrU@zuFVlj0fOHkpcPpS4PU/V3Dz/f43))

```
OrderedDict([(1, 'foo at 1')])
foo at 1
OrderedDict([(1, 'foo at 1'), (2, 'foo at 2')])
foo at 2
OrderedDict([(1, 'foo at 1'), (2, 'foo at 2'), (3, 'foo at 3')])
foo at 3
OrderedDict([(2, 'foo at 2'), (3, 'foo at 3'), (4, 'foo at 4')])
foo at 4
OrderedDict([(2, 'foo at 2'), (4, 'foo at 4'), (3, 'foo at 3')])
foo at 3
OrderedDict([(4, 'foo at 4'), (3, 'foo at 3'), (1, 'foo at 1')])
foo at 1
```

Comment: Downvoted. Firstly, what you implemented is not an LRU cache to begin with, as it does not move the most recently used item to the front. Secondly, your dict-based implementation does not work in Python 2, where dict keys are unordered. Thirdly, the inclusion of `col_name` in the cache key is redundant since each `col_name` has its own cache. And lastly, testing if the return value of `cache.get(cache_key)` is None is prone to error since you can't tell if you're getting `None` because the given key is missing or because the value of the key is actually `None`.

Comment: @blhsing Good points, thank you for your feedback. I have revised the code accordingly.

Comment: It appears that the Python 3 LRU cache avoids rehashing a key. Even though in this case computing the hash does not appear to be particularly expensive, you are needlessly hashing the key twice if the key is in the cache first by your checking if the key exists in the dictionary and then again when you get the key's value. You can avoid this by doing `value = self.cache.pop(key, sentinel)` and then seeing if what is returned is the sentinel, i.e. some value that cannot possibly be in the cache.

Comment: @Booboo Thank you for the feedback, I have updated the code to use a sentinel value.

Answer (score 3):

An LRU cache is simply a mapping that preserves insertion order so the most recently used item can be moved to the front and the least recently used item can be removed when the maximum size of the cache is reached. In both Python 2 and Python 3, such a data structure can be found in the standard library as [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.popitem) with the `popitem(last=False)` method.

To more easily initialize an LRU cache for each column name, you can also use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict

class Client:
    def __init__(self, cache_size=3): # a cache size of only 3 for demo purposes
        self.col_cache = defaultdict(OrderedDict)
        self.cache_size = cache_size

    def get_col(self, col_name, time):
        cache = self.col_cache[col_name]
        try:
            cache[time] = cache.pop(time)
        except KeyError:
            if len(cache) >= self.cache_size:
                cache.popitem(last=False)
            cache[time] = '%s at %s' % (col_name, time) # make DB query here
        print(cache)
        return cache[time]
```

so that:

```
c = Client()
print(c.get_col('foo', 1))
print(c.get_col('foo', 2))
print(c.get_col('foo', 3))
print(c.get_col('foo', 4))
print(c.get_col('foo', 3))
print(c.get_col('foo', 1))
```

outputs:

```
OrderedDict([(1, 'foo at 1')])
foo at 1
OrderedDict([(1, 'foo at 1'), (2, 'foo at 2')])
foo at 2
OrderedDict([(1, 'foo at 1'), (2, 'foo at 2'), (3, 'foo at 3')])
foo at 3
OrderedDict([(2, 'foo at 2'), (3, 'foo at 3'), (4, 'foo at 4')])
foo at 4
OrderedDict([(2, 'foo at 2'), (4, 'foo at 4'), (3, 'foo at 3')])
foo at 3
OrderedDict([(4, 'foo at 4'), (3, 'foo at 3'), (1, 'foo at 1')])
foo at 1
```

Demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVLNasMwDL7nKQSjJIFQ2LLDKGSHrdtlhz1AKcEkymrm2J6swLKXz5y2cdOOXuabpe/Pkm3PO6PzB0vD0JBpoTJKYcXSaAeytYYYamxEp7iWFWfwTjUS1mt/iaJKCefgWUnUvIrAH4@FspRaclkmDlWTQSWqHZZO/mCRpyu4AXEowVgC04DRqoccGkOe3hqwHVnj0O0FxzPqLH2w8sAr5omSWaD0ghGMPeV0iULQD@TSy045vYEWLWbAssV0FcQm1/MYmwm/DUCm/sQKzM0ot50iLK2xyd4gIPG7Qsvwhv0LkaFzCdmAQp3suSk8FpdPO0cH09FGMraJ3xAXr0K5meHfaPHCgWBYuBgWkFxMwq@sFZ8I6yf46pB62PmBBzFLUvMxXygSckd6buI/i/c5fJUkjY6s5bSCuDEmzuA2vdq6u97Kr7fu/8XyMYbhFw)

Note that since Python 3.2, `collections.OrderedDict` also has a [`move_to_end`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.move_to_end) method for you to move an item to the front, so you can change the line:

```
cache[time] = cache.pop(time)
```

to simply:

```
cache.move_to_end(time)
```

Answer (score 0):

We may preserve the login of an existing implementation of `lru_cache` but organise a mapping of chosen argument values to separate caches within an outer decorator. Here is a sample implementation:

```py
from functools import lru_cache, wraps
from inspect import getcallargs


def lru_agrument_cache(argument_name):
    def decorator(function):
        callable_buckets = {}

        @wraps(function)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            inspection = getcallargs(function, *args, **kwargs)
            
            # should use functools._make_key() for more general use
            bucket_key = inspection[argument_name]

            if bucket_key in callable_buckets: 
                return callable_buckets[bucket_key](*args, **kwargs)
            
            callable_buckets[bucket_key] = lru_cache(function)

            return callable_buckets[bucket_key](*args, **kwargs)
        
        # just to demonstrate usage
        def cache_info(argument_value):
            try:
                return callable_buckets[argument_value].cache_info()
            except KeyError:
                return None

        wrapper.cache_info = cache_info
        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

Usage:

```py
@lru_agrument_cache('key')
def my_callable(key, times):
    return key * times
```

Verify:

```bash
my_callable('A', 2)
Out[16]: 'AA'
my_callable('A', 2)
Out[17]: 'AA'
my_callable('A', 3)
Out[18]: 'AAA'
my_callable('B', 2)
Out[19]: 'BB'

my_callable.cache_info('A')
Out[20]: CacheInfo(hits=1, misses=2, maxsize=128, currsize=2)
my_callable.cache_info('B')
Out[21]: CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=1, maxsize=128, currsize=1)
```

- `inspect` is also available in `Python 2.*`;
- `functools.lru_cache` is to replace with that `lru_cache` currently is use;
- [`functools.wraps`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/functools.py#L65) and it's dependency [`functools.partial`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/functools.py#L276) if not available, may than be taken from sources.
- not sure what to add concerning thread safety though;